# Split the column in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, split

I am trying to split a column in pyspark on a bunch of delimiters: "_", "-", "|", "\", "/" etc. So if the data frame is as follows:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo-23.aBD"), (2, "bar12/bg_$"),(3,"iO9_5Gh"),(4,"fg4555(dfd")],["id", "label"] )
```

I would like to have the values "foo", "bar12", "i09" and "fg4555" in the column "label".
I can do this separately, for each delimiter:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col 

split_col = functions.split(df['label'], '-')
df = df.withColumn('label', split_col.getItem(0))
split_col = functions.split(df['label'], '_')
df = df.withColumn('label', split_col.getItem(0))
split_col = functions.split(df['label'], '/')
df = df.withColumn('label', split_col.getItem(0))
```

But it doesn't look nice. Is there any possibility to do this in a more compact way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to split on word boundaries (`\b`). Somehow, `_` is not a word boundary, so you need to add that to the list of patterns too.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('label', F.split('label', '(\\b|_)')[0])

df2.show()
+---+------+
|id |label |
+---+------+
|1  |foo   |
|2  |bar12 |
|3  |iO9   |
|4  |fg4555|
+---+------+
```